# quiero que mis botones lleven la scollbar a una una zona especifica de la pagina de manera fluida

Tags: javascript, python, django

estoy trabajando con python-django y con el framework bulma pero este problema es en el archivo de js

html

```
<a class="navbar-item" id="boton_about_me">
<a class="navbar-item" id="boton1_Curriculum">
```

variables

```
const obtener = () => document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

esta linea si funcinciona y lleva la barra arriba

```
const ir_about_me = () => {
if (obtener() > 0 ){
requestAnimationFrame(ir_about_me)
scrollTo(0,obtener () - (obtener() / 50 ));
 }}

document.getElementById('boton_about_me').onclick = ir_about_me
```

el problema esta cuando lo intento poner en otro punto de la pagina la barra se vuelve loca

```
const irCurriculum = () => {
if (obtener() > 860 ){
  requestAnimationFrame(irCurriculum)
  scrollTo(0,obtener () - (obtener() / 20 ));
     }
  else if (obtener() < 860 ){
     requestAnimationFrame(irCurriculum)
     scrollTo(0,obtener () + (obtener() / 20 ));
  }
  }
  document.getElementById('boton1_Curriculum').onclick = irCurriculum
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que [window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) tiene usos bastante diferentes de un simple desplazamiento:

> El método window.requestAnimationFrame informa al navegador que quieres realizar una animación y solicita que el navegador **programe el repintado de la ventana para el próximo ciclo de animación**. El método acepta como argumento una función a la que llamar antes de efectuar el repintado.

Hay otras opciones más adecuadas como la propiedad CSS [scroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior), aunque la desventaja es que los navegadores basados en *Chromium* no la aplican por defecto, teniendo que modificar la configuración.

```css
html, body {
    /* Esta regla es suficiente */
    scroll-behavior:smooth;
}
#about-me, #curriculum {
    min-height:100px;
    background:#ddd;
    margin:300px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<nav id="top">
    <a class="navbar-item" href="#about-me">Acerca de mí</a>
    <a class="navbar-item" href="#curriculum">Curriculum</a>
</nav>
<div id="about-me">
    Contenido de "Acerca de mí"<br>
    <a href="#top">Arriba</a>
</div>
<div id="curriculum">
    Contenido de "Curriculum"<br>
    <a href="#top">Arriba</a>
</div>
```

También se puede lograr con un poco de Javascript, detectando clic en los enlaces a anclas dentro de la misma página y aplicando el desplazamiento con [window.scroll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll#ejemplo):

```js
// Desplazar suavemente hasta el elemento deseado
function smoothScroll(item) {
    window.scroll({
        // Tomar desplazamiento desde el elemento
        top: item.offsetTop,
        left: 0,
        // Este atributo es el que hace la magia
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
}
// Escuchar clics en todo el documento
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Buscar solo enlace con ancla a misma página
    // Si el elemento que recibió clic no es enlace y no tiene ancla, el resultado será null
    let link = e.target.closest('a[href^="#"]');
    // ¿El enlace es un ancla?
    if(link) {
        // Separar enlace y ancla
        let [href, hash] = link.href.split('#');
        // Buscar destino por ID
        let dest = document.getElementById(hash);
        // Solo si existe el destino
        if(dest) {
            // Cancelar evento para evitar salto brusco
            e.preventDefault();
            // Mostrar destino con función
            smoothScroll(dest);
            // Actualizar hash en ventana
            history.pushState(null, null, '#' + hash);
        }
    }
});
```

```css
#about-me, #curriculum {
    min-height:100px;
    background:#ddd;
    margin:300px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<nav id="top">
    <a class="navbar-item" href="#about-me">Acerca de mí</a>
    <a class="navbar-item" href="#curriculum">Curriculum</a>
</nav>
<div id="about-me">
    Contenido de "Acerca de mí"<br>
    <a href="#top">Arriba</a>
</div>
<div id="curriculum">
    Contenido de "Curriculum"<br>
    <a href="#top">Arriba</a>
</div>
```

Con cualquiera de estas dos opciones que elijas vas a lograr que todos los enlaces con anclas en la misma página tengan el comportamiento deseado.

Answer (score 0):

Las pocas veces que he querido hacer eso he usado esto:

```
function scrollToElement(pageElement) {    
    var positionX = 0,         
        positionY = 0;    

    while(pageElement != null){        
        positionX += pageElement.offsetLeft;        
        positionY += pageElement.offsetTop;        
        pageElement = pageElement.offsetParent;        
        window.scrollTo(positionX, positionY);    
    }
}

var pageElement = document.getElementById("header");
scrollToElement(pageElement);
```

Quizá te interesa usar los tags de posición con `#elementId`

Y te mueves con: `location.hash = "elementId"`